# Model View Controller (MVC) : Model & Data Types

Tags: model-view-controller, types, architecture, model

Suppose you have an N-Tier, MVC architecture of your (java or *) application. You chose MVC for its logical, manageable partitioning of the application code. 
Suppose you are into Java, since there are many frameworks or tools out there, you don't want to tie a Layer (M or V or C) to a specific technology, and would like to maintain the freedom for later upgrades or even integration with other parts.

Now, in every scenario, a Model may contain primitive data types (like Int, String..etc), or more advanced ones in the form of classes (OO features for max complexity).
How would you deal with that:

- keep your Model as POJO as you can, and implement the typing at the V or  C layer, since it is mostly about data input and validation . This way, you don't have to worry about your Model being used elsewhere, almost nothing will change at the DAL as well, but you have to do extra effort to convert your model to a rich-model (rich in types); when you transfer it from the storage to the view
- enable your Model to support types as other nested Models, and implement V or C layer tricks to deal with it, each Layer will have to process the model-complex, instead of just using getters and setters.  However this way, you keep the model-complex in other technological settings, which should be adapted accordingly.
- [none of the above or else]

Answer (score 1):

I think the technology is irrelevant if you wanna go fully distributed. I would create separate apps for each layer, which you can easily cluster and then choose a standardized communication format like JSON over HTTP(s).

JSON can be as simple or complex as you like and pretty much every language out there has support for it built in.

HTTP is fast and simple, and very easy to scale.

Just my two cents.

Comment: OK, so the Model will be as simple as possible, for the sake of standardized communications, after all, it's the hardest part to maintain!

Comment: It really depends on what sort of application your trying to build. The DB is almost always the bottleneck and yes, can be a real pain to maintain. But any system must be maintained at some level. I would still suggest using some sort of ORM framework to simplify queries and then analyze all queries to optimze indexes on the relevant tables... I have built this sort of extreme distributed apps before, but need some more info into what exactly you are trying to achieve. 

If performance is an issue you can always look at binary JSON as opposed to plain text JSON to save a few bytes.

Comment: Also the big advantage of using something like JSON is that it stays standardized through all your layers. On the DB side it's just transforming a result set into text, on the controller its very easy to manipulate, and on the view you can do some pretty funky javascript processing on it as well (assuming it's a web app)

Comment: Yes, JSON is seamlessly transportable, specifically for webapps (I meant MVC for webapps).
Here the issue is not performance but maintainability and extendability.
You said 'The DB is almost always the bottleneck', are you referring to performance of the hardships of maintaining a changing Schema ? I guess the latter is hard indeed.

Comment: Indeed, a changing schema is just an unavoidable nuisance when dealing with a live system that is constantly growing. I personally use ALOT of unit and functional testing to ensure schema changes don't adversely affect the system as a whole. But it's not perfect. In terms of performance, I've found that using a NoSQL solution together to the more traditional relational structure is fantastic with reporting. But yet again, it adds complexity and more potential maintenance.

Comment: I guess what it comes down to when designing any sort of architecture is the end goal. What do we need now and what will we need in a year or two? How "big" is the system? How many users now and in the future? How much data are we dealing with? etc. etc.

The only advice I can give is: Keep it as simple as possible. Once you start over-designing your gonna run into trouble. Good luck mate.